# How to create radar chart/spider chart with ploylt.js

Tags: javascript, charts, plotly, radar-chart

I just started to use plotly.js with react.
Right now I want to make a radar chart with 18 angular coordinates, but since there is no radar chart in plotly.js, I am not sure what is the best way to do that.

I found the two ways to do but not perfect.

1. The first way the I found is to use a polar chart to make a radar chart, but have some issues. [image] I am setting radical coordinates (r) and angular coordinates (t) like this   `r: [60, 72.5, 70.0, 45.0, 60.5], t: ["math", "history", "music", "english", "geography"]` for the left chart in the picture; however, since angular coordinates are strings, I can not connect first coordinate and last coordinate with a line as you can see in the picture.

The next issue is that if I have more than 6 coordinates, a chart does not   show all angular coordinates. In the right chart in the picture, I set coordinates like this `r: [60, 72.5, 70.0, 45.0, 60.5, 60, 30, 20, 10], t: ["math", "history", "music", "english", "geography", "logic", "ethic", "aaaa", "bbbb"]`, and it only shows 5 out of 9 angular coordinates while I want it to show every coordinate.

2. The second way is to create a chart like [this](https://plot.ly/~empet/13752/radar-chart/#plot), but I feel like this is not the efficient way to do that. Since it looks like that I have to write every detail of the chart, it would not be flexible to adapt different data.

These are the things that I found so far, but I feel like I am missing an easier way to make a radar chart in plotly.js. It can not be this much complicated and inefficient to create a radar chart.

I know there are other libraries such as chart.js that support radar chart, but I need to do this in plotl.js

What is the best way to create a radar chart in plotly.js?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW RGraph supports a canvas Radar chart:

http://www.rgraph.net/demos/radar-non-filled.html

And from the next version will support an SVG Radar chart too. It will probably save you a butt load of time.